# Can't create new schema in an OVH postgres

Tags: postgresql, ovh

I have a PostgreSQL server on OVH's Cloud DB and have been using its databases for my web apps.
So far so good.
I got a project where It's a requirement to have schemas. Strangely enough, **I am unable to create schemas on the user with "Administrator" privileges.**
I have prepared scripts using schemas, so I just need to run them on a prepared database but I need a database with schemas to run them.

Here is my process:

1. Create a new database
2. Select option "Create user"
3. Select option for privilages: "Administrator"
4. Commit configuration
5. Wait for database creation
6. Connect to database with the new config via PGAdmin
7. Run command `create schema if not exists "vMobile";`
8. Recieve following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for database my-database-dev
SQL state: 42501
```

I created a ticket for this but the wait is taking too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Support answer

Ok, so I got a response from the OVH support and there is no option for the user to create new schemas as their CloudDB enables access only to schema public and mentioned privileges `Administrator, Read/Write, Read, None` are only applicable to the `public` schema.

#### Workaround

My solution to this is to create tables with schema name included in their names
like so:

- Desired outcome: `"vCommon"."Route"`
- Workaround: `"public"."vCommon_Route"`